# DeviceIoControl works in C++ and C# but return ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION when called in C++/CLI

Tags: c++-cli, deviceiocontrol

I am trying to enumerate the MFT to get list of file names.

This code works when used in a Win32 project:

```
MFT_ENUM_DATA med;
med.StartFileReferenceNumber = 0;
med.LowUsn = 0;
med.HighUsn = ujd.NextUsn;
BYTE pData[sizeof(DWORDLONG) + 0x10000];
DWORD cb;
while (DeviceIoControl(handleToVolume, FSCTL_ENUM_USN_DATA, &med, sizeof(med),
  pData, sizeof(pData), &cb, NULL) != FALSE) {
 //do the processing
}
```

But when I use the same code in C++/CLI, `DeviceIoControl` gives false and `GetLastError` gives ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION.
When the same code is translated into C#, it works.

Any idea what is happening?

Comment: You should beware of `GetLastError` in managed code. You're supposed to put the right flag in your DllImport attribute, and use `Marshal::GetLastWin32Error` instead... Also, even though it isn't supposed to have an influence, you should initialize `cb` to zero before the call.

Comment: I am using unmanaged `DeviceIoControl`. I tried `Marshal::GetLastWin32Error` too and it gives the same value 1 as `GetLastError`. Also initialized `cb`, but no good.
I am now wondering if this is caused by some project setting or properties...

Answer (score 0):

check if you have this define:

```
#define FSCTL_ENUM_USN_DATA 
 CTL_CODE(FILE_DEVICE_FILE_SYSTEM,44,METHOD_NEITHER,FILE_READ_DATA)
```

and replace `FILE_READ_DATA` with `FILE_ANY_ACCESS`